# Phrase "A existed as little as B years ago"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, phrases

I'm curious about phrase

> "A existed as **B (adverb or adjective)** as C years ago"

or more specifically,

> "A existed as **little** as C years ago"

The original sentence is like the below.

> Active stock markets now exist and attract foreign investments in many cities where the concept of foreign private investment through a regulated public market barely **existed as little as twenty years ago**.

Answer (score 1):

> "A existed **as little as** C years ago"

has the meaning:

> A existed C years ago, and C years is very little time.